# OpenVPN won't start as a service with config file

Tags: ubuntu, openvpn

I've got OpenVPN working good with my config file if I run it from CLI:

```
openvpn server.conf
```

But if I try to start it as a service it starts just fine, won't error out, but it will not load my conf file since there is no resulting `tun` device in `ifconfig`.

I have `AUTOSTART` set to `all` in `/etc/init.d/openvpn`:

[image]

But a quick `ifconfig` shows it's not started. I know it's not loading my conf file since the log file is not created, but no errors from OpenVPN.

[image]

This is on Ubuntu 16.04.3, fresh clean install of OpenVPN.

**EDIT**

As per comments below I have tried multiple times also with `systemctl`, it just errors out:

[image]
[image]

I know the conf file works since I can run it from CLI as `openvpn server.conf` and it works.

**EDIT2**

Logs:

```
Jan 11 14:31:37 cloud systemd[1]: openvpn@server.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jan 11 14:31:37 cloud systemd[1]: openvpn@server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jan 11 16:06:07 cloud systemd[1]: Starting OpenVPN connection to server...
Jan 11 16:06:07 cloud ovpn-server[4726]: OpenVPN 2.3.10 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH] [IPv6] built on Jun 22 2017
Jan 11 16:06:07 cloud ovpn-server[4726]: library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016, LZO 2.08
Jan 11 16:06:07 cloud ovpn-server[4726]: daemon() failed or unsupported: Resource temporarily unavailable (errno=11)
Jan 11 16:06:07 cloud ovpn-server[4726]: Exiting due to fatal error
Jan 11 16:06:07 cloud systemd[1]: openvpn@server.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jan 11 16:06:07 cloud systemd[1]: Failed to start OpenVPN connection to server.
Jan 11 16:06:07 cloud systemd[1]: openvpn@server.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jan 11 16:06:07 cloud systemd[1]: openvpn@server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jan 12 09:55:35 cloud systemd[1]: Starting OpenVPN connection to server...
Jan 12 09:55:35 cloud ovpn-server[12133]: Current Parameter Settings:
Jan 12 09:55:35 cloud ovpn-server[12133]:   config = '/etc/openvpn/server.conf'
Jan 12 09:55:35 cloud ovpn-server[12133]:   mode = 1
Jan 12 09:55:35 cloud ovpn-server[12133]:   persist_config = DISABLED
Jan 12 09:55:35 cloud ovpn-server[12133]:   persist_mode = 1
Jan 12 09:55:35 cloud ovpn-server[12133]:   show_ciphers = DISABLED
Jan 12 09:55:35 cloud ovpn-server[12133]:   show_digests = DISABLED
Jan 12 09:55:35 cloud systemd[1]: openvpn@server.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jan 12 09:55:35 cloud systemd[1]: Failed to start OpenVPN connection to server.
Jan 12 09:55:35 cloud systemd[1]: openvpn@server.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jan 12 09:55:35 cloud systemd[1]: openvpn@server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Comment: Not sure why you are messing with `init.d`. Have you tried `systemctl start openvpn@server.service`?

Comment: Check `/etc/default/openvpn` and please as @multithr3at3d stated, don't change init files.

Comment: I've done that also, it errors out. I will post what it does above.

Comment: Can you post text rather than screenshots please.

Comment: And post the rest of the error logs, too.

Comment: Those are the only error logs, I'm not sure why the screenshots won't work? If you click it, they come up large.

Comment: The logs are truncated in the last screenshot; can you post the entire error message? Try `journalctl -u openvpn@server.service -e` for the last 1000 lines, and try to post the entire log from when it starts to when it fails.

Comment: I have added the full logs

Comment: You appear to have the same solvable problem as https://askubuntu.com/q/747023/778746

Comment: That worked thank you, you can post as the answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem is the same as [another posted on Ask! Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/747023/778746). The [fix](https://askubuntu.com/a/747146/778746):

> What I have found to work is to comment out the LimitNPROC line in /lib/systemd/system/openvpn@.service.

Answer (score 0):

When I tried to run my server config I found that it was unable to reassign same port thus I reboot server and got fixed the issue.

```
ubuntu@VPNSERVER:/etc/openvpn$ sudo openvpn server.conf
Fri May 28 18:09:18 2021 OpenVPN 2.4.4 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD] built on Apr 27 2021
Fri May 28 18:09:18 2021 library versions: OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018, LZO 2.08
Fri May 28 18:09:18 2021 ECDH curve prime256v1 added
Fri May 28 18:09:18 2021 Outgoing Control Channel Encryption: Cipher 'AES-256-CTR' initialized with 256 bit key
Fri May 28 18:09:18 2021 Outgoing Control Channel Encryption: Using 256 bit message hash 'SHA256' for HMAC authentication
Fri May 28 18:09:18 2021 Incoming Control Channel Encryption: Cipher 'AES-256-CTR' initialized with 256 bit key
Fri May 28 18:09:18 2021 Incoming Control Channel Encryption: Using 256 bit message hash 'SHA256' for HMAC authentication
Fri May 28 18:09:18 2021 TUN/TAP device tun1 opened
Fri May 28 18:09:18 2021 TUN/TAP TX queue length set to 100
Fri May 28 18:09:18 2021 do_ifconfig, tt->did_ifconfig_ipv6_setup=0
Fri May 28 18:09:18 2021 /sbin/ip link set dev tun1 up mtu 1500
Fri May 28 18:09:18 2021 /sbin/ip addr add dev tun1 10.8.0.1/24 broadcast 10.8.0.255
Fri May 28 18:09:18 2021 Could not determine IPv4/IPv6 protocol. Using AF_INET
Fri May 28 18:09:18 2021 Socket Buffers: R=[212992->212992] S=[212992->212992]
# ===>>>>>  blow line was error that I found <<<<<<<===== #
# Fri May 28 18:09:18 2021 TCP/UDP: Socket bind failed on local address # [AF_INET][undef]:1122: Address already in use (errno=98)
Fri May 28 18:09:18 2021 Exiting due to fatal error
Fri May 28 18:09:18 2021 Closing TUN/TAP interface
Fri May 28 18:09:18 2021 /sbin/ip addr del dev tun1 10.8.0.1/24


   **ubuntu@VPNSERVER:/etc/openvpn$ sudo reboot**
```

In your case OPenVpn status and restart command could be like

```
systemctl status openvpn-server@server.service
 systemctl restart openvpn-server@server.service
```